# Is the application of the Drum-Buffer-Rope (DBR) concept in this example wrong?

Tags: constraints, scrumban, theory, drum-buffer-rope

In order to undertand Scrumban I researched and found this book: *[Scrumban: And Other Essays on Kanban Systems for Lean Software Developmentby Corey Ladas](https://a.co/d/hYPsAjB)*.

In this book I encountered the Theory of Constraints (ToC) and Drum Buffer Rope (DBR) concepts. Here is a corresponding excerpt from the book:

> Imagine we have team of three people, each working as generalists in an agile-style
> process. They are all qualified and competent workers, and correctly
> execute the process that they intend to follow. They break their work
> up into customer-valued features that each take a few days to complete
> through integration. One developer is a true generalist. It takes her
> a couple of days to produce a testable functional specification and
> high-level design. It takes her a couple of days to produce a detailed
> design and working code. And it takes her a couple of days to verify
> and validate everything, from code correctness to functional
> acceptance. Another developer is basically competent at all of these
> things, but he is a more stereotypically geeky programmer who can
> crank out high-quality code for most product features in a day, on
> average. It takes him a bit longer than the others to do the
> customer-facing part, usually about 4 days for analysis and high-level
> design. He’s also a bit slower with the validation, because again, if
> it ain’t writing code, he’s just not that excited about it. And for
> all the time he spends on specs, they are still mediocre, which
> results in rework in spite of his good coding skills. The third
> developer, by contrast, has a sharp eye for design and is very
> friendly and sympathetic to the business and the customers. He knows
> the business so well that most of his specs only take a day to write.
> He’s a competent coder, but a bit old-school in his style and it takes
> him a bit  longer with the current technology. Plus, his heart isn’t
> quite in it the way it used to be. It takes him three days to develop
> good code that everybody will feel comfortable with. On the other
> hand, since his specs are so clean and thorough, and he has a good
> rapport with the business, the testing usually goes very smoothly in
> about two days, also (tied for) the best on the team. The team, on
> average, produces features with a cycle time of 6.67 days per feature.
> Overall, each team member produces at a similar rate. 2d + 2d + 2d =
> 6d 4d + 1d + 3d = 8d 1d + 3d + 2d = 6d
> 20 days
> / 3 features = 6.67 days/feature It is a one-piece flow (per
> developer), and everybody is always busy with his or her feature.
> Nobody ever has to wait to start a new feature. Other than the
> personal slack built into the task times, capacity utilization is
> high. But imagine if this team of generalists were allowed to focus
> only on the skills that they were best at: 1d + 1d + 2d = 4d 1d + 1d +
> 2d = 4d 1d + 1d + 2d = 4d
> 12 days / 3 features = 4
> days/feature Same people, same features, 40% improvement in
> productivity... ...if only it were that simple, because there is also
> a cost here. If they organize themselves as a pipeline, then that
> pipeline becomes subject to the Theory of Constraints. If they apply
> Drum-Buffer-Rope, then the testing task sets the pace at 2 days.
>
> That means the total cycle time per feature is: 2d + 2d + 2d = 6d

Please explain why `2d + 2d + 2d = 6d`? If you use DBR, I believe it should still take `1d + 1d + 2d = 4d`, i.e. we place a buffer in front of the bottleneck to make sure the bottleneck constantly works. What am I missing?